# Logging in wordpress user with Oauth token

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, oauth

Is it possible to allow loggin in user into wordpress(woo commerce) with Oauth token? And also adding data to user cart is possible with REST API?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can use cocart plugin for cart operations. But it doesn't support authentication.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart-rest-api-for-woocommerce/

You can examine "JWT Authentication for WP REST API" plugin for authentication.
https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/